# How do I add panels programatically and edit them?

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have a panel that gets information from an API, and displays it, this information changes every second, and sometimes some information is removed or replaced.
Currently I have this:
[image]

I have found a way to create panels programatically, along with the labels, but how would I edit each label according to the information obtained.

I have this code:

```
Guna2GradientPanel info = new Guna2GradientPanel();

info.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(this.panel_Paint);
info.Size = new Size(681, 41);
info.Location = new Point(21, 74);
info.FillColor = Color.FromArgb(23, 24, 45);
info.FillColor2 = Color.FromArgb(23, 24, 45);
info.BorderRadius = 5;
            
info.ShadowDecoration.BorderRadius = 12;
info.ShadowDecoration.Enabled = true;
info.ShadowDecoration.Color = Color.FromArgb(10, 10, 28);
info.ShadowDecoration.Shadow = new Padding(10, 10, 10, 10);
info.ShadowDecoration.Depth = 3;

InfoDisplayPanel.Controls.Add(info);
```

But another problem I ran into is that I can't do this function outside of the form class, I can't add this panel to the main panel since I can't access panels from a static function, and the program is getting the info via another class and thread, I need to somehow access this function from another thread/class.

Comment: You may be able to store them in a dictionary to easily find one. You can also create a custom control incorporating those required per row to handle all of this very easily, and maybe use a flowlayoutpanel to put them in.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

I'm assuming that there is a `static class` which loop that periodically checks the API for new values.

Create an interface for the form where the panel lives to implement.

Ex:

```
interface IPanelAPI {
    void Update(SomeValues vals);
}
```

Add a property to the `static class` `public IPanelAPI PanelAPI { get; set; }`

Then set this property to an instance of the Form.

Implement the logic for updating the panel in the `Update()` method on the form.

Call `Update()` from within the loop when new info arrives.

Note:
Look into `Invoke()` in order to update the UI from a non UI thread.